PayPal v2 API Patching failed because of JSON pointer error
I am creating a customer PayPal Class.  The current flow is the user orders, clicks paypal, and approves the price. Once approved, we collect the delivery address from PayPal, and get a shipping price. We then update the order with the delivery price and updated Vat and Total Order Value.
This is the error I keep getting:

{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"field":"path","value":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=="default"/amount","location":"body","issue":"INVALID_JSON_POINTER_FORMAT","description":"Path should be a valid JSON Pointer https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901 that references a location within the request where the operation is performed."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"c*******d","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_JSON_POINTER_FORMAT","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}

This is the template for the order:
$order = [
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'application_context' => [
                'return_url' => BASE_URL . 'shoppingcart/view_papa_cart.php?pp=ret', // Replace with your return URL
                'cancel_url' => BASE_URL . 'shoppingcart/view_cart_update.php?pp=can', // Replace with your cancel URL
            ],
            'purchase_units' => [
                [
                    'description' => 'Order', // Update as needed
                    'amount' => [
                        'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'], // Update based on your currency
                        'value' => '0', // The total will be calculated in the loop below
                        'breakdown' => [
                            'item_total' => [
                                'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'], // Update based on your currency
                                'value' => '0', // The total will be calculated in the loop below
                            ],
                            'shipping' => [
                                'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                                'value' => '0' // Initial value for shipping
                            ],
                            'tax_total' => [
                                'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                                'value' => '0' // Initial value for tax (VAT)
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    'items' => [],
                ]
            ],
        ]; 

This is the patch code I want to update:
$patchData = [
            [
                'op' => 'replace',
                'path' => '/purchase_units/@reference_id=="default"/amount',
                'value' =>  [
                    'value' => number_format($newTotal, 2, '.', '')
                ],
                'breakdown' => [
                    'item_total' => [
                        'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                        'value' => number_format($itemTotal, 2, '.', '')
                    ],
                    'shipping' => [
                        'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                        'value' => number_format($deliveryPrice, 2, '.', '')
                    ],
                    'tax_total' => [
                        'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                        'value' => number_format($vatAmount, 2, '.', '')
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]; 

Based on the error, it is this part which is causing the issue:
'op' => 'replace',
                'path' => '/purchase_units/@reference_id=="default"/amount',
                'value' =>  [
                    'value' => number_format($newTotal, 2, '.', '')
                ],

I have spend some time trying to figure it out but I can not get the code working properly. I did have a lot of errors but now it's just this one.  Could someone please help and point me in the right direction.

Okay, so the issue was down to how you create the patch json object. This is how it should look:
 $patchData = [
            [
                'op' => 'replace',
                'path' => '/purchase_units/@reference_id==\'default\'/amount',
                'value' => [
                    'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                    'value' => number_format($newTotal, 2, '.', ''),
                    'breakdown' => [
                        'item_total' => [
                            'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                            'value' => number_format($itemTotal, 2, '.', '')
                        ],
                        'shipping' => [
                            'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                            'value' => number_format($deliveryPrice, 2, '.', '')
                        ],
                        'tax_total' => [
                            'currency_code' => $_COOKIE['PriceNameCookie'],
                            'value' => number_format($vatAmount, 2, '.', '')
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

But although this is a fix, if you change the price, you need the user to again re approve the new price. In this case you are going around in circles.
But that is a different problem altogether. I wanted to clear this part up as I spent a long time on it, and the instructions on PayPal are vague as it only demonstrates how to change an address.
I hope this helps someone out there :-)
